# Геолокация с использованием FusedLocationProviderClient выборочно не работает

Tags: android-studio, геолокация

Я создал приложение с определением координат устройства по этому примеру:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#play-services

Геолокация работает у меня на смартфоне (версия Андроид 4.4), но не работает на мобильных устройствах с версиями 6 и 7. В руководстве ничего не сказано о том, что FusedLocationProviderClient должен быть deprecated в более поздних версиях Андроид. Как мне пофиксить эту проблему?

Код моего приложения здесь:
https://github.com/tivewsalaeharad/SMSonRoad

Comment: Пермишены в рантайме запрашиваете?

Comment: Да. Конечно:  (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

Comment: Это проверка, а запрос-то где?

Comment: В MainActivity.OnCreate я пишу mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

Comment: Где Вы запрашиваете у пользователя разрешения на доступ к `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` и `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`?

Comment: Я прописываю это в манифесте

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: А RequestPermission в данном случае нужно вызывать до LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient?

Comment: По логике -- да.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72914/discussion-between---and-post-zeew).